# IPV6 API call with NodeJS on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, ipv6, axios

I'm trying to figure out how to make an API call to my Ubuntu/NodeJS server that is running on DigitalOcean using an IPV6 address.
With an IPV4 address, the API call looks like this:

```
axios.get('http://[IPV4_ADDRESS_HERE]:3000/api/loginStatus?userID=123')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

I tried doing this for the IPV6 call, but no luck:

```
axios.get('http://[IPV6_ADDRESS_HERE]:3000/api/loginStatus?userID=123')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I got my app rejected from Apple because they only accept apps that work on IPV6 connections, so I'm trying to do this so I can get in the App Store.

On the server, I am using express for the REST API:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var PORT = 3000
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
    next();
});
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'))

app.listen(PORT, "::", function() {
        console.log("running on port", PORT)
} );
```

Comment: As Apple's docs explain, you should avoid using literal IP addresses and use a domain name instead.